# Replace lines of text in iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am needing to replace a line of text in code on my iOS app, however the lines that need to be replaced in the particular NSString will be different for different entries on the XML that is being parsed.

For example, I need to replace 129727-the-cave.mp3 with 129727.jpg.

However, I can't just tell it to replace -the-cave.mp3, because some instances of the string will have a different number and title of mp3.  I think the next line is:

129838-my-song.mp3.

So, basically, I need a way to find everything from the first hyphen through mp3 and replace it, no matter what the text is?

Comment: You might want to read up on regexes, they're just for this kind of thing. Try this http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288

Comment: You can detect the first "-" `rangeOfString` and delete what's after with `subgStringFromIndex`. An other method: `componentsSeparatedByString` and use the object at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *original = @"129727-the-cave.mp3";
NSString *sub = [original substringToIndex:[original rangeOfString:@"-"].location];
NSString *finalString = [sub stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
NSLog(@"finalString: %@", finalString);
```